# Clientside GWT and Maven curious Setup

Tags: java, javascript, maven, gwt

I want to setup GWT in a special mode. I only use GWT for the client side as a replacement for having to deal with JavaScript directly.

The idea is to produce a single JS file.

Since this is also part of a bigger project with multiple project pages I got a problem where to put the output of the compiler and how to setup.

The ideal setup would be placing the GWT stuff into a single project and incooperate the ouput in a different project. The question is how to do it?

Update:

The current plan is to compile the JavaScript out of GWT using a simple Java application just issuing the GWT compile command and taking the Eclipse auto-build classes as necessary input. After the sources are compiled to java script the application copies the js files (one for every supported browser) to the related destination. This way the once created js files stay static and other developers do not have to deal with GWT related build tasks and we just avoid a necessary maven fight to get things working on build.

Also the GWT project can now depend on the web project making it possible to start the web application and alter its behaviour by adding support to host mode debugging.

Does anyone know a working example?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, if you build a WAR in the end, is to put the output of GWT in a WAR too that you can use an an *overlay* in the final WAR module.

Other Maven plugins could do the trick too ([`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html), maven-shade-plugin, etc.)

See https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes for examples.

Comment: There wont be a war file. It is using an embedded jetty without a web.xml.

Comment: Then you could just package them as a JAR I guess (depends how you intend to load them from Jetty though, which possibly also depends how you're going to distribute and run the app)

Comment: What I want is the JS file becoming part of another project automatically. So it is not actually build but contributed on development time and checked in on commit. It is a bit odd but it prevents the other developers to enjoy the fun of installing and dealing with GWT.

Comment: So they're just resources that you'll serve as _static resources_ from your embedded Jetty, right? That depends how you serve static content with Jetty then.

Comment: Static content is simply streamed by the in house framework. Jetty is out of the way so we can seamlessly pick up the right JavaScript version to server depending on the user-agent information of the request.